# CSS Vertically align content in the center of a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a header with a logo and a mobile navigation icon. Each of which are insider their own div which is inside a parent container div. I want the contents of each div to be vertically aligned to the middle, and it should stay that way when the page is resized ( page is responsive). I tried setting each div, both parent/child css property of vertical-align middle and it does not work. I also read to change the display property of the parent div to table, and then change each child div to display table-colum then use vertical-align but if I do that the rest of my header is not displayed properly. Is there anyway I can vertically align my content?

Here is my code as-is. I removed my vertical-align code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style>
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#logoContainer {
       display: inline-block;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#logo {

    width: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    min-width: 90%;
}

#menu{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;

}

#mobileMenu {

    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
</style>


<link href="content/hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">




</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="logoContainer">

        <img id="logo" src="content/logo.png" />

    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <button class="hamburger hamburger--elastic" type="button">
            <span class="hamburger-box">
                <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
            </span>
        </button>

    </div>

</div>



<div id="mobileMenu">
    add somome content

</div>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of like 50 questions....

Comment: you can just search vertical-align div(or any element) you will get your answer...

Comment: Already tried vertical- align like I said in my post. Cant use flex box due to IE issues since I have to support 8

Comment: @Scott have you see this answer yet?? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div